# Continous data generator from Azure Databricks to Azure Event Hubs using Spark with Kafka API but no data is streamed

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub, data-stream

I'm trying to implement a continuous data generator from Databricks to an Event Hub.

My idea was to generate some data in a `.csv` file and then create a data frame with the data. In a loop I call a function that executes a query to stream that data to the Event Hub. Not sure if the idea was good or if spark can handle writing from the same data frame or if I understood correctly how queries work.

The code looks like this:

```
def write_to_event_hub(
    df: DataFrame,
    topic: str,
    bootstrap_servers: str,
    config: str,
    checkpoint_path: str,
):

    return (
        df.writeStream.format("kafka")
        .option("topic", topic)
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrap_servers)
        .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")
        .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
        .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", config)
        .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path)
        .trigger(once=True)
        .start()
    )


while True:
    query = write_to_event_hub(
        streaming_df,
        topic,
        bootstrap_servers,
        sasl_jaas_config,
        "/checkpoint",
    )
    query.awaitTermination()
    print("Wrote once")
    time.sleep(5)
```

I want to mention that this is how I read data from the CSV file (I have it in DBFS) and I also have the schema for it:

```py
streaming_df = (
    spark.readStream.format("csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .schema(location_schema)
    .load(f"{path}")
)
```

It looks like no data is written event though I have the message "Wrote once" printed. Any ideas how to handle this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `readStream` to get the CSV data, so it will wait until new data will be pushed to the directory with CSV files.  But really, you don't need to use `readStream`/`writeStream` - Kafka connector works just fine in batch mode, so your code should be:

```py
df = read_csv_file()
while True:
  write_to_kafka(df)
  sleep(5)
```

Comment: It works but now I try to figure out if I read the data in the kafka format in another notebook how do I convert the data from the kafka format back into my schema

Comment: it depends on which format have you used when writing data into Kafka - often people use JSON, Avro, or something else. Kafka itself doesn't know about data - both keys & values are binary values, and format of the actual data is a contract between producers & consumers